# React Native Firebase Chat app - Add Listener for new incoming messages

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, chat, addeventlistener

I'm creating a chat feature in my application that leverages Firebase. I've read the docs about adding event listeners, but I can't seem to get the listener to update the state (I believe when the state gets updated, the app re-renders and should have the new, incoming message)

Use Case:
you're having a chat with someone and you have the messaging/chat screen up and dont want to have to refresh the page to see new messages... they should display as the message gets posted to the DB

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        this.pullMessages()
        this.listener()
        this.setState({ isLoading: false })
```

```
   pullMessages = () => {
        let messagesArray = []
        if (this.state.chatroomDetails.users.length === 2) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('private').collection(this.state.chatroomDetails.key).doc('messages').collection('messages').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        messagesArray.push(doc.data())
                        this.setState({ messages: messagesArray })
                    })
                }
            })


        }
        else {
            firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('group').collection(this.state.chatroomDetails.key).doc('messages').collection('messages').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        messagesArray.push(doc.data())
                        // console.log(messagesArray)
                        this.setState({ messages: messagesArray })
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log('Nothing to Grab')
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

```
 listener = () => {
        let messagesArray = []
        if (this.state.chatroomDetails.users.length === 2) {
            firebase.firestore().collection('chatrooms').doc('private').collection(this.state.chatroomDetails.key).doc('messages').collection('messages')
                .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                            console.log('the console');
                            console.log(doc.data());
                            messagesArray.push(doc.data())
                        })
                    }
                })
            this.setState({ messages: messagesArray })
        }
    }
```

in listener(), i can see the new message that comes through from the other device, but i can't seem to set it to my state from here... help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is likely not updating because you are mutating it. When this line runs:

```
messagesArray.push(doc.data())
this.setState({ messages: messagesArray })
```

You are adding an item to the messages array that is already in the state and then setting the state to the same value which won't re-render your component.

You can correct this by setting the messages value to a new array each time you receive an update on the collection. Like this:

```
this.setState({ messages: [...messagesArray, doc.data()] })
```

EDIT:

I have also noticed that your state update is not in the snapshot listener here:

```
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            console.log('the console');
                            console.log(doc.data());
                            messagesArray.push(doc.data())
                        })
                    }
                })
            this.setState({ messages: messagesArray })
```

It should look this like:

```
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            this.setState({ messages: [...messagesArray, doc.data() })
                        })
                    }
                })
```

or even better to prevent needlessly updating the state:

```
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                        const newMessages = querySnapshot.map((doc) => doc.data())

                        this.setState({ messages: [...messagesArray, ...newMessages })
                    }
                })
```

Comment: your solution looks very promising, but i keep getting 'cannot read property 'setState' of undefined :/

Comment: This is a binding issue in react. Try changing `function(querySnapshot) {...}` to `() => {...}`

Comment: i've pulled your code and its working, i have to get rid of my 'pullMessages()' function because i believe they're doing the same thing now? 

I'm now running into a problem where it keeps adding the whole state over again (so duplicate messages) with the new message added to the bottom :/

Comment: Yeah, those two functions would be doing the same thing. The duplicated messages is an easy fix. Just change `messages: [...messageArray, ...newMessages]` to `messages: newMessages`

Comment: @CampbellMG can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color